# What is meant by "the world of the Manes"?

Tags: brihadaranyaka-upanishad

The Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, Section V, [Verse 1.5.16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117941.html) states:

> *There are indeed three worlds, the world of men, the world of the Manes and the world of the gods. This world of men is to be won through the son alone, and by no other rite; the world of the Manes through rites; and the world of the gods through meditation. The world of the gods is the best of the worlds. Therefore they praise meditation.*

What is meant by "the world of the Manes"?

Comment: Why don't you google it, here is the meaning "the souls of dead ancestors, worshipped as beneficent spirits". This question​ is more of an English language question rather than Hinduism related question.

Comment: @Yogi Asking users to google is not recommended. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31104/why-do-so-many-people-ask-basic-questions-instead-of-searching-first/31109#31109) on Meta.SE and [this post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/should-i-search-on-internet-before-asking-question) on our site.. We can only ask for more research effort.  Answering is recommended than commenting.

Comment: Manes are the souls of our Ancestors(paternal- father, grandfather, great grandfather, so on to 7th generations back). I had read about maternal manes too, and they are maternal ancestors' should back to 5 generations. But I doubt whether maternal ancestors are souls of Mother, grandmother et cetera or grandfather.

Comment: world of Gods= Devaloka , world of Manes= Pitrloka.

Comment: Thanks again. I am familiar with devaloka & manussaloka (human world) from Buddhism. Regards

Comment: Sorry. "Manes"is certainly an English word. Learn something new nearly every day. No wonder my googling was not successful since I was googling "manes upanishad" and only found text. Thanks again

Comment: @SreeCharan okay, how is this question related to Hinduism? O0 is asking question related to English language which happens to be used in Upanishadic gloss.

Comment: No problem. The description of the pitru loka is also described in some texts. Adding that in your question will increase the quality of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> अथ त्रयो वाव लोकाः—मनुष्यलोकः **पितृलोको** देवलोक इति; सोऽयं
>   मनुष्यलोकः पुत्रेणैव जय्यः, नान्येन कर्मणा; कर्मणा पितृलोकाः, विद्यया
>   देवलोकः; देवलोको वै लोकानां श्रेष्ठः, तस्माद्विद्यां प्रशंसन्ति। ॥ १६
>   ॥
>
> atha trayo vāva lokāḥ—manuṣyalokaḥ **pitṛloko** devaloka iti; so'yaṃ
>   manuṣyalokaḥ putreṇaiva jayyaḥ, nānyena karmaṇā; karmaṇā pitṛlokāḥ,
>   vidyayā devalokaḥ; devaloko vai lokānāṃ śreṣṭhaḥ, tasmādvidyāṃ
>   praśaṃsanti || 16 ||
>
> There are indeed three worlds, the world of men, **the world of the
>   Manes** and the world of the gods. [**Brihadaranyaka Upanishad
>   1.5.16**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117941.html)

Pitriloka has been translated as 'World of Manes'. [Pitris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitrs) are the ancestors who departed from this world and reside in Pitriloka. One may attain Manushya Loka or Pitri loka or Deva Loka as per their Karma.

Answer (score 4):

In **Brihadaranyaka Upanishad**: Now, these are, verily, the three worlds: the world of men, the **world of the Manes and the world of the gods.** The world of men can be gained through a son only and by no other rite; the world of the Manes through rites; and the world of the gods through meditation. The world of the gods is the best of the worlds. Therefore they praise meditation.

> **The world of the Manes means pitris or ancestors** and **Manes - souls of dead ancestors**

And appeasing the Manes is even more important than pleasing the Gods as said in the following verse:

> Manu Smriti 3.203. For twice-born men the rite in honour of the manes is more important than the rite in honour of the gods; for the offering to the gods which precedes (the Sraddhas), has been declared to be a means of fortifying (the latter).

In Adition, It is **one of 3 runas (debts)** we borrow when taking birth as a man - to **pitrus**, which is repaid by begetting a son doing tarpana/shraddam.

Answer (score 2):

> *‘Yājñavalkya,’ said he, ‘how many kinds of oblations will the
> Adhvaryu offer in this sacrifice to-day?’*
>
> *‘Three.’ ‘Which are those
> three?’*
>
> *‘Those that blaze up on being; offered, those that make a
> great noise, and those that sink.’ ‘What does he win through them?’
> ‘Through those that blaze up on being offered he wins the world of the
> gods, for this world shines, as it were. Through those that make a
> great noise he wins the world of the Manes, for this world is full of
> uproar. And through those that sink he wins the human world, for this
> world is lower.’*
>
> [Verse 3.1.8](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc118302.html)